# Raspberry Pi RT Preempt Linux Kernel Build Error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, raspberry-pi3, preempt-rt

I am trying to Build and install a Raspberry Pi RT Preempt Linux Kernel.

These are the steps that I had followed:

1. I installed the pre-compiled kernel `kernel-4.4.9-rt17.tgz`
2. I downloaded Raspberry Pi kernel sources and applied the Real Time [`patch-4.4.9-rt17.patch.gz`](http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203).
3. I configured my kernel for Raspberry Pi3, Model
   B using:

   ```
   export KERNEL=kernel7
   make bcm2709_defconfig
   ```
4. I configured the kernel to support Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT) using

   ```
   make -j$(nproc) menuconfig
   ```
5. I built the kernel using

   ```
   make -j$(nproc) zImage
   ```

   but I received the error:

   ```
   In file included from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:14:0:
   ./include/linux/sched.h:2040:32: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘&’ token
   #define tsk_cpus_allowed(tsk) (&(tsk)->cpus_allowed)
                                   ^
   ./include/linux/sched.h:3679:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘tsk_cpus_allowed’
   static inline const struct cpumask *tsk_cpus_allowed(struct task_struct *p)
                                        ^
   In file included from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:14:0:
   ./include/linux/sched.h:3687:19: error: redefinition of ‘tsk_nr_cpus_allowed’
    static inline int tsk_nr_cpus_allowed(struct task_struct *p)
                      ^
   In file included from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:14:0:
   ./include/linux/sched.h:2042:19: note: previous definition of ‘tsk_nr_cpus_allowed’ was here
   ```

[Here is the kernel build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGvJh.png)

Do you have any idea to solve this?  I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have been stuck at this for some time now and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: After the build fails, display the environment with the `printenv` command, which will probably reveal your mistake(s).  Are you compiling on the RPi or some other host?  BTW you should not be building as root.

Comment: I am compiling on the RPi.So I didn't cross-compile the kernel

Comment: i am facing similar problems with kernel 4.6.y. Hope you get help or get it done ...

Comment: printenv didn't help me to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Problem solved by installing a  NON precompiled kernel (version 4.4.50). I used the corresponding 4.4.50-rt63 rt-patch. The errors happened because of a mismatch between the pre-compiled kernel and the rt-patch that I used. Thank you for your answers.